# JavaScript not working in Grails/GSP

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
​$(function () {
    $('#add').click(function() {
        $(this).before($('select:eq(0)').clone());
      if ($('select').length > 5) $(this).hide();        
    });
});​
//-->
</script>
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<select name="dropdown">
    <option value="a">Apple</option>
    <option value="b">Bee</option>
    <option value="c">Cat</option>
    <option value="d">Donkey</option>
    <option value="e">Elephant</option>
</select>
<a href="#" id="add">Add</a>
```

In the jsfiddle demo its working fine, but its not working on my gsp. Any idea or I am missing out something? Whenever I click on the "Add" it just display /# on my url.

The error message I managed to figure out through inspecting the element is as follows:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

[image: Error Message]
**Screenshot**
[image: Console error screenshot from Chrome]

Comment: Is the browser debugger showing any errors when you click the Add link?

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL". I suspect that the way I declare the script on the gsp is wrong? The "Add" is unable to point to the script I guess.. But I have no idea on how to troubleshoot it..

Comment: What does the GSP-generated code look like on the browser?  (i.e., use "View source" or your browser's equivalent)

Comment: the script is in the header and the html drop list is in the body, although i didnt do any header/body tags in my gsp

Comment: And is the script intact/unmangled?

Comment: Hold on I'll screenshot the error on the view page source

Comment: Unable to post the screenshot due to insufficient rep.. Anyway yes the script is intact. But there's the error message on the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably some illegal characters in the <script> block.

Did you copy/paste it from somewhere else? I would suggest you put cursor at the start and end of each line and delete all characters till you are sure there are no non-visible characters.

Alternatively delete the whole script block and retype it manually

Comment: It worked when I tried it on jsfiddle demo, both the script and the html. I will try your suggestion and get back. Thank you!

Comment: actually when i copy over from jsfiddle into a local file, i get the same error that you are getting.

Comment: looks like some stray chars. i'll post a screenshot in your question. let me know if that is what you see.

Comment: great! as you can see there were some ugly looking chars 'â€‹' .when i deleted those, it worked fine

Comment: you have to add the jquery-1.8.2.js lib to your page

Answer (score 0):

Try uncommented version (w/o `<!--` and `//-->`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
​$(function () {
  $('#add').click(function() {
     $(this).before($('select:eq(0)').clone());
     if ($('select').length > 5) $(this).hide();        
  });
});​
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you but the script still doesnt work.. Its still returning the same page with a # in the url.

Comment: Waht if you add `console.log('add')` into function? btw, as I see, this code should open `#` (and hide button before open), isn't it?

Comment: The code should/is to clone an identical drop list whenever the user click on add. Nothing happens when I add that in..

Answer (score 0):

You can probably avoid issues like this if you just put the JavaScript in an external file.

Comment: Though I have no experience with GSP, I assume that everything in the HTML source is subject to reinterpretation by the GSP engine.  Putting the JavaScript code in an external file would reduce the risk of GSP mangling the code somehow; it should just serve up the .js file directly (this is how most web frameworks work, anyway).

Comment: If a framework messes the js it will do it regardless of its location. But Grails doesn't mess with the js, as far as I can tell.